# Multiple Parent IDs on jqgridtree?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, tree

I have a scenario where the IDs are unique but can have multiple Parents.

how is that possible?

http://www.trirand.net/demotreephp.aspx

```
media
...books
  ...fiction
      ...comedy
      ...mystery
  ...nonfiction
      ...history
      ...science
...cds
  ...music
  ...audio-books
      ...fiction
        ...comedy
        ...mystery
      ...non-fiction
        ...history
        ...science
...dvds
  ...narrative
      ...comedy
      ...mystery
  ...documentary
      ...history
      ...science
```

Comment: Why it shouldn't be possible? Is it conflicts with tree data structure or with html/http principles? Explain what you mean, please. And give link for that example, if it available on-line. You link leads to a page with another model.

Comment: its not easy?do u know?if you have multiple parent a one item and when clicked a parent,all same child nodes expand where under the another parent nodes.